# Logging data obtained from txt file

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, logging, graphing

I'm currently a beginner in Python, and I'm currently working on obtaining data from a txt file and producing a graph for `log(x)` vs `log(y)`.

This was the basic code, where it would plot the data from the txt file.

```
data = loadtxt ("values.txt", float)
plot(data[:,0],data[:,1])
show()
```

Graph produced:

[image]
However, I want to log both x and y. How do I approach this?

Comment: If you are using matplotlib then check out http://www.labri.fr/perso/nrougier/teaching/matplotlib/#simple-plot for example and link to plot() command and tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this out.

```
import numpy as np

data = loadtxt ("values.txt", float)

x_data = np.log(data[:,0]) # here we are logging over the whole n-dimensional array
y_data = np.log(data[:,1])

plot(x_data, y_data)
show()
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks for the help!

Comment: Awesome! I'm glad :) Don't forget to mark the answer correct!